# Progress Dialog don't show

Tags: c#, .net, mahapps.metro

My code

```
protected async Task SyncAll()
{
    var ProgressAlert = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait...", "Sync....");  //show message
    ProgressAlert.SetIndeterminate(); //Infinite

    try
    {
       //some magic code here
       //show info
       await ProgressAlert.CloseAsync();
       await this.ShowMessageAsync("End","Succes!");
    }
    catch 
    {
        await ProgressAlert.CloseAsync();
        await this.ShowMessageAsync("Error!", "Contact with support");
    }

}

private async void SyncButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await SyncAll(); 
}
```

And I only receive a dimmed window and no ProgressDialog.
I want execute my code and manipulate inside him with ProgressDialog instance.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you want to do?
can you write the messagebox text in english? so we can understand well...

Comment: This doesnt matter, i want show ProgressDialog, do something in try block, and hide ProgressDialog.

Comment: the "magic code" is it non blocking (i.e. using await properly)?

Comment: Nope, this magic code don't use any new Thread or Await etc.

Comment: @user3468055 I think there is your problem then, you are blocking the ui thread hence the ui can not update the progressalert

Comment: If i migrate this function to async thread this didn't solve me issue...

Comment: without seeing the code it's impossible to say...

Comment: It's specific Polish ERP API Calls. Nothing standard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people explained in the comments, the issue is probably that your "Magic code" is probably synchronous, and blocks the whole UI. What you want to do is make this call asynchronous.

One easy way to do this will be to call `Task.Run` around your synchronous code.

Let's say you put your "Magic Code" into a method that is called `MyMagicCode()`.

```
protected async Task SyncAll()
{
    var ProgressAlert = await this.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait...", "Sync....");  //show message
    ProgressAlert.SetIndeterminate(); //Infinite

    try
    {
       await Task.Run(() => MyMagicCode());

       //show info
       await ProgressAlert.CloseAsync();
       await this.ShowMessageAsync("End","Succes!");
    }
    catch 
    {
        await ProgressAlert.CloseAsync();
        await this.ShowMessageAsync("Error!", "Contact with support");
    }

}
```